# Desktop Window Manager crashes randomly

Tags: windows-7, dwm

I have been having a problem where the Desktop Window Manager (on Windows 7) crashes randomly.  Typically, there is no BSOD, but the entire computer locks up.  On a couple occasions it has recovered and told me that Desktop Windows Manager crashed.  Most of the time I don't want to wait so I hard reboot by removing power sources to the machine.  When it crashes, I can move the mouse and click on things, but nothing happens (although I believe it is recorded, as the actions are performed on recovery).  Also, I cannot bring up Task Manager during the crash.

I found the report in Windows Action Center from the most recent time it crashed and recovered:

```
Source
Desktop Window Manager

Summary
Stopped working

Date
‎8/‎14/‎2012 2:10 PM

Status
Report sent

Description
Faulting Application Path:  C:\Windows\System32\dwm.exe

Problem signature
Problem Event Name: APPCRASH
Application Name:   Dwm.exe
Application Version:    6.1.7600.16385
Application Timestamp:  4a5bc541
Fault Module Name:  igd10umd64.dll
Fault Module Version:   8.14.10.1930
Fault Module Timestamp: 4aba7355
Exception Code: c0000005
Exception Offset:   00000000000e9040
OS Version: 6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.4
Locale ID:  1033
Additional Information 1:   3089
Additional Information 2:   3089af789c8e8cb9755b456a58763597
Additional Information 3:   8b07
Additional Information 4:   8b07ed81f6f979a8ae6568fb945eff23

Extra information about the problem
Bucket ID:  9943401
```

I have been Googling this with no success so far.  It seems to occur most often while running Chrome/YouTube, so I could just avoid that, but I'd like to understand why this is occurring.

BTW, I have 8GB of RAM, of which I only use 2-3GB.

**EDIT:** My computer is a laptop, the chip type is "Mobile Intel 965 Express Chipset Family".  The adapter string is "Mobile Intel GMA X3100".

Answer (score 1):

Most likely it is a graphics driver issue. Can you make sure that you are using the latest version of your graphics drivers? If you don't know how to do that, state which video card you have and we can help you find them. Also, make sure you have installed all Windows Updates and Service Packs and that you are not running any desktop shell customization programs such as WindowBlinds.

Comment: @PhillipR. Instead of commenting that you agree, it is more helpful to upvote (and it avoids clogging the comments).

Comment: @allquixotic, see edit for graphics card details.  AFAIK, I have all the Windows Updates installed (the computer is on a regular update schedule).  I believe the graphics drivers are up to date as well but will look into that.

Comment: The latest Intel graphics drivers for the 965GM are [here](http://downloadcenter.intel.com/Detail_Desc.aspx?agr=Y&ProdId=2301&DwnldID=18223&ProductFamily=Graphics&ProductLine=Laptop+graphics+drivers&ProductProduct=Mobile+Intel%C2%AE+945GM+Express+Chipset+Family&lang=eng)

Comment: It was a driver issue for us. Since we had this problem on a Windows 2K8 R2 Server, and we don't have any hope of a stable graphic driver on a server Blade, we fixed it by disabling Aero.